# html tag attribute displayed in unicode

Tags: php, html, unicode, character-encoding

I have the following code, from which you can see that, I use the same way to create the text in utf-8. The text shown between html tags are shown correctly. But the text shown as html tag attribute are shown in unicode. I'm positive that on the server side(PHP), both texts are treated in the same way and are encoded in utf-8. 
Why the text as html tag attribute shown in unicode?

```
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="&#x88E6;&#xE791;&#xB188;&#x89E6;&#xE693;&#x988A;"/>
  <title>看看大家都在分享什么最新火爆的购物打折信息? </title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>

<li id="nav_logout">
       <a href="http://www.example.com/test/svn/main/logout" title="&#x9000;&#x51FA;&#x672C;&#x7AD9;">退出</a>
       <span></span>
</li>
```

Comment: Which browser is exhibiting this behavior? Is there a good reason you're converting the characters to HTML entities instead of just putting them in there directly?

Comment: seen this problem on Firefox(MAC) and Safari.

Well, for the meta description, I have to put them as tag attribute of 'content'

Comment: My question is not "why are you using attributes", it's "why are you not just putting the characters in the attributes as-is instead of converting them to &# syntax".

Comment: Hi Michael,that's exactly my problem. In my php code on the server side, I put utf-8 encoded text as the value of "content". But on the client side, it shows unicode. If I put the same text between tags(as tag content), it shows correct text.

Comment: Okay, that's STILL not what I'm trying to ask. Let's try this: Why are you using `title="&#x9000;&#x51FA;&#x672C;&#x7AD9;"`instead of the equally valid `title="退出本站"`? And perhaps you could show a screenshot of the exact issue, so it's more clear exactly what your problem is?

Comment: HI Michael,in my server side code php, I wrote, <?php echo <a href=example.com title="退出本站">退出本站</a>;?>
But when it's shown in client browser, the title value becomes unicode "&#x9000;&#x51FA;&#x672C;&#x7AD9;"
I'm not using those codes. It just shows up. I'm trying to solve this problem.

Comment: PHP doesn't change anything to HTML entities (the `&#x9000;` stuff) unless you tell it to. If this is what's being sent to your browser, then somewhere, you're either calling some code to do that, or the data you're getting is already in that format instead of plain characters. You're going to have to show the exact piece of code that generates this if we're to have any hope of figuring this out.

Comment: Here is the server code: 
echo "<meta name=description content=退出/>";

Here is the client side displayed:
<meta name=description content=&#x9000;&#x51FA;&#x672C;&#x7AD9;/>

Comment: `Unicode` is just a catalogue. You probably mean `HTML entities`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, they *should* be echoed as-is and not converted into HTML entities - Something is doing just that. I'd venture to guess that you're feeding your output through a function that does that using the output buffering system. Search your code for *(all, they stack)* instances of **[`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)** being called and tell us the first argument (which is the callback of the function that the output is fed through).